# How to fix problems when Laravel pages are not loading properly after uploaded to the host

Tags: laravel-5

I have uploaded my first Laravel project folder to the host and when I load the page it appears broken but it works properly in localhost. Do not know how to fix, some advice would be great. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You will need to provide more information such as where you are hosting, installation steps etc.

Comment: I hosted it on Bluehost. I did everything right but wasn't sure about file permission. Anyways, it's fixed now. Thanks for your response